Cuda Unified Memory not transfering to Kernel
I was working on debugging a project of mine and ran into an issue where I believe my unified memory has not properly transferred to the device. The following is a simplified code snippet of how I was trying to use the unified memory:
#include "DebuggerDeviceHelper.cuh";
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(int elems) {
        cudaMallocManaged((void**)&map, elems * sizeof(char*));
    }

    void set_index(std::string str, int index) {
        cudaMallocManaged((void**)&map[index], (str.length() + 1) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(map[index], str.c_str(), (str.length() + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }

    __device__ void test_print() {
        printf("test\n");
    }

    char** map;
};



__global__ void test_kernel(TestClass* test_class) {
    char** arr = test_class->map;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    TestClass h_test_class(5);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 1", 0);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 2", 1);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 3", 2);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 4", 3);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 5", 4);
    TestClass* d_test_class;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_test_class, &h_test_class, sizeof(TestClass*), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    test_kernel << <1, 1 >> > (d_test_class);
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorName(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

which returns a cudaErrorIllegalAddress.
As per this post, unified memory should be transferred to the device on kernel launch.
Manually passing in the char array as a parameter works without error:
__global__ void test_kernel(char** arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    TestClass h_test_class(5);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 1", 0);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 2", 1);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 3", 2);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 4", 3);
    h_test_class.set_index("Test 5", 4);
    char** arr = h_test_class.map;
    test_kernel << <1, 1 >> > (arr);
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorName(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}


The first argument in cudaMemcpyToSymbol is a pointer to a global variable in __device__ or __constant__ memory. Not an uninitialized local variable. Please also do basic error checking for your runtime library calls

Allocating CUDA Unified Memory by overloading operator new causes illegal access might be of interest. Not because the issue is the same, but because overloading operator new or using memory resources (see my answer) are probably better ways of handling this in C++.
